# how do i add an autocompletion in my IDE to use Zend helper

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, netbeans, zend-studio

I'm using Zend studio. When I want to use a helper my editor doesn't see it. So I couldn't have in a list of methods for autocompletion (when I press crtl+space).

I can use any another IDE like netbeans or eclipse. So please if someone have done something like that, it could be helpful for me.

I'm sure that we have some method because in documentation we have:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile(...);
// appenfile, prependfile, ....
```

Comment: Which autocompletion ? php functions ?

Comment: no! not php functions but a functions which are psecific to Zend !! i have take an example with headscript which has many methods but when i press Crtl + Space i have "No suggestions"

Comment: I know what you're looking for... you've got something like a ViewHelper that you'd like to load, something like `My_View_Helper_Thing`. The ZF code just needs `Thing`, but the IDE doesn't know how to code complete for that. I never have found a way to do that. Technically, I'm not entirely sure it's possible with the way ZF actually decides which class to use. Zend Studio is your best bet, though the last time I used it (2 years ago), it didn't seem to have this.